# Python: IndentationError

Tags: python

**I'm using the following code and I get an indentation Error, how can I fix this?**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):

outcome_var = 'LoanAmount'

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

predictor_var = ['Credit_History','Gender','Married','Education']

classification_model(model, df,predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

> *File "", line 3
>        outcome_var = 'LoanAmount'
>
> ```
>         ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block*
> ```

Comment: Anything inside the function body needs to be indented

Comment: Well, indent the code within the function, as the error suggests

Comment: You don't have a body for that function.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python the scope is defined using indentation

you have a function defined with `def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):` so this function needs some statements. 
The `outcome_var='LoanAmount'` statement needs to be indented to include it in the function, and all other statements that belong to this function must follow the same indentation

For example:

```
def function_with_no_statements():
    pass

print("Here")

def print_something(something):
    print(something)

print("Here 2")

print_something("Here 3")
```

If you run the above example you will see that the print("Here") statment is not in any function, also print("Here 2"), if you call the print_something function it will print whatever you sent it (in other words execute the indented statement

Comment: There is nothing needing indenting, `outcome_var` is one of the variables passed in as a parameter.